# Numerical integration of highly oscillating function containing SphericalBesselJ

Tags: numerical-integration, convergence

I am using the following code to integrate my function containing spherical Bessel function.

```
v = 1;
rv = r/v;
(*txy=tx-ty;*)
S0[txy_, rv_] := (2/3)*((txy^2 - rv^2)^2/rv^3)*(rv^2 + 6 rv + 12);
S1[txy_, rv_] := (2/3)*(txy^2 - rv^2)/
    rv^3*(-txy^2*(rv^3 + 12 rv^2 + 60 rv + 120) + 
     rv^2*(rv^3 + 4 rv^2 + 12 rv + 24));
S2[txy_, rv_] := (1/6)*(1/
     rv^3)*(txy^4*(rv^4 + 20 rv^3 + 180 rv^2 + 840 rv + 1680) - 
     2 txy^2 rv^2*(rv^4 + 12 rv^3 + 84 rv^2 + 360 rv + 720) + 
     rv^4*(rv^4 + 4 rv^3 + 20 rv^2 + 72 rv + 144));

IFunction[txy_, rv_] := 
  8 \[Pi]*(Exp[txy/2] + 
     Exp[-txy/2] + (txy^2 - (rv^2 - 4*rv))/4*rv*Exp[-rv/2]);

DeltaS[k_] := 
  NIntegrate[
   v^3*k^3*Exp[-rv/2]/
     IFunction[txy, rv]*(SphericalBesselJ[0, v k rv]*S0[txy, rv] + 
      SphericalBesselJ[1, v k rv]/(v k rv)*S1[txy, rv] + 
      SphericalBesselJ[2, v k rv]/(v k rv)^2*S2[txy, rv])*
    Cos[k txy], {txy, 0, Infinity}, {rv, Abs[txy], Infinity}, 
   Method -> "MultidimensionalRule", PrecisionGoal -> 50, 
   MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 60];

DeltaS[1]
DeltaS[2]
Table[DeltaS[k], {k, 0, 10}]
```

However, I get the following error messages:

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
>
> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 0.038649669160045507754190812899896036482231699482913281511750129560983848433366701011584109440819620442663818214`110. and 8.3733083843025581773485914936116025034536685784296471804912551049086479416227610296631069256616752164643869246`110.*^-9 for the integral and error estimates.

Are there any good solutions or methods to solve my problem?

Comment: Do you really need this high precision? Try to set intermediate points in NIntegrate, e.g., NIntegrate[...,{txy,0,π,∞},...]. Remember that SphericalBesselJ[{0,1,2},x] can be simplified in terms of Sin[x] and Cos[x], see FunctionExpand[SphericalBesselJ[{0, 1, 2}, x]].